# Where does the wordpress stores the domain names and when is it "not reserved"?

Tags: database, validation, wordpress

I am creating a multisite wordpress blog.I am doing the registration with my own code as opposed to the wordpress signup.
Everything works except I get this error `"Sorry!that site is reserved"` at times.This is not always though.I am having a hard time sorting out the logic behind this.I have checked database for the domain with the same name But i don't find even a trace of it.When i type the url in the browser it say the site does not exist yet.

What am I missing?
And the problem that this creates is that the user is already registered with the email and i have to provide different signup details to make a new site.I have to start all over again.
I am doing the validation via Ajax and making sure that everything is par requirement to avoid this situation.But there is one condition that I am missing.Please help me find that.thanks.

Updated:
The error seems to have been generated from ms-functions.php line no around 697.I cannot seem to understand the logic behind the code.It,I think says that if the username exists with the blogname,check if the $user is an object and the login is whether or not the equal to the blogname,if the blogname doesnot equal the username(user_login) or the user is not an object kill the code.
I might have solved this while writing this question.I'll check

Comment: I don't have an answer. But can you give more details. Are you trying to create subdomains, or complete new domains? what plugins do you use that affect MU?

Comment: No I am trying to create a subdomain.The error seems to have been generated from ms-functions.php line no around 697.I cannot seem to understand the logic behind the code.I will edit my code answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that the username and subdomain cannot be the same (apparently!!)
I have checked the condition and is working fine.But it may not be the real problem,may be just the coincidence.I still welcome to any suggestion and clue regarding this problem.